# Combine two queries in linq

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I have two linq queries as follows:

```
GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects 
        = new ObservableCollection<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect>(
                                  from g in db.Groups
                                  select new GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect
                                                {
                                                    GroupID = g.GroupID,
                                                    GroupName = g.GroupName,
                                                    CorrespondingEffect = g.Master_Effects.Effect

                                                }
                                         );

 GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects 
          = new ObservableCollection<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect>       
                       (GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects.
                            Where(u => !GetAllChildren(25).
                                        Select(x => x.GroupID).
                                        Contains(u.GroupID)).ToList());
```

Now how can I combine these two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass directly this to the constructor of the `ObservableCollection`:

```
from g in groups
let g = select new GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect
        { 
            GroupID = g.GroupID,
            GroupName = g.GroupName,
            CorrespondingEffect = g.Master_Effects.Effect
        }
where !GetAllChildren(25)
       .Select(x => x.GroupID)
       .Contains(g.GroupID)
select g
```

I'm not sure if EF is able to compose the first and the second part (I can't remember from the top of my head if `Contains` is resolved in an `IN` clause, my EF is a bit rusty), but you were not doing that anyway, so the effect is the same as yours. If it is able to compose, then this way you are getting a more efficient execution.

Comment: I have tried your answer as well as the other answer from Neil. In both the cases I get following error : `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[WPF_Client.HelperClasses.GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect] GetAllChildren(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated `

Comment: Ok, EF cannot compose it, as I was suspecting. It should be as easy as extracting GetAllChildren(25).Select(x => x.GroupID).ToList() in a variable and use that one to do the Contains. If that one raises the same problem, you can take Neil's answer and just add a ToList() before the .Where call. The second part will run in memory, but it's not different from what you were doing in your code anyway.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this line : `The second part will run in memory, but it's not different from what you were doing in your code anyway.` Also thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind mixing SQL-style and extension method syntax, you can do this:

```
GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects 
        = new ObservableCollection<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect>(
                (from g in groups
                 select new GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect
                     { GroupID = g.GroupID,
                       GroupName = g.GroupName,
                       CorrespondingEffect = g.Master_Effects.Effect
                     })
                 .Where(u => !GetAllChildren(25)
                        .Select(x => x.GroupID)
                        .Contains(u.GroupID))
                 .ToList());
```

Comment: I have tried your answer as well as the other answer from Wsap. In both the cases I get following error : `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[WPF_Client.HelperClasses.GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect] GetAllChildren(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated `